# Regex for numbers with spaces, plus sign, hyphen and brackets

Tags: regex, phone-number

I am looking for regex for a telephone number but cant seem to find what i need.

Requirements

- start with a plus sign (optional) eg. +442021234
- allow brackets (optional) eg. (+44)2021234
- allow any length of numbers
- allow spaces between numbers eg. (+44) 202 1234
- allow hyphens eg. (+44)-202-1234

Basically want to allow users to enter a telephone number with common special characters and will strip these away with JavaScript onBlur. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? That's a long list of requirements (not including the stripping of the characters); do you have any code we can help debug or are you asking us to write it for you?

Comment: Why not strip the characters first, and then just validate that you have 9 digits with Regex using `^\d{9}$`? That way, when you display the number, you can format it again however you'd like, so that it's consistent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: Due to the way the website is setup, I am unable to strip the values before validation as this is triggered automatically. So i want to allow users to enter plus, hyphens, brackets and spaces and strip them away with JS after validation.

The telephone number is split into 3 seperate input fields (country code, area code and phone number). It is a large system so i have many restrictions - one is that i have to use the same regex on all three boxes so i do not want to restrict the user in how many numbers they can enter.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 9):

You can try this regex:

```
/(?:\(?\+\d{2}\)?\s*)?\d+(?:[ -]*\d+)*$/
```

Comment: This seems to cover most of what im looking for but i need it to not allow letters and ideally only a plus at the start of the number. Is this possible?

Comment: This won't allow letters and`+` is only optional at start. Didn't you need that?

Comment: Thanks correct. I have got the point where need a seperate regex for a list of the special characters so the validation is not triggered when it executes. Regex with plus sign, hyphen and brackets.

Comment: So should I take out matching `+` and `( )` ?

Comment: I guess to answer the original question - Yes.
However, if you could also write a new regex which only allows '+', '-' and '()' - that would be great!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41477/discussion-between-dvl-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following Regex...

```
^\(?\+?[\d\(\-\s\)]+$
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching the format, since you plan to strip the characters regardless, why not strip the characters first and then validate you have a number that's the length you require?

```
// strip all non-numeric values
var number = number.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

// validate we have a number of a specific length
if (number.length == 9) {
    // valid number =]

}
```

If you have additional "number" rules, such as it *has* to start with `44`, you could then use a regex after you've stripped the characters:

```
if (number.match(/44\d{7}/)) {
    // we have a (+44)* number

}
```